# No type conversion is performed by a type assertion?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Typescript, just a question on type assertion.

Below is an example from my textbook:

```
function calculateTax(amount: number, format: boolean): string | number {
   const calcAmount = amount * 1.2;
   return format ? `$${calcAmount.toFixed(2)}` : calcAmount;
}

let taxNumber: string | number = calculateTax(100, false);
let taxString: string | number = calculateTax(100, true);
```

and the book which says:

**No type conversion is performed by a type assertion, which only tells the compiler what type it should apply to a value for the purposes of type checking. SO they are equivalent to these statements**

```
let taxNumber: number = calculateTax(100, false) as number;
let taxString: string = calculateTax(100, true) as string;
```

I'm confused, so `calculateTax(100, false)` is `string | number`,when we do the assertion by append as number to it, `calculateTax(100, false) as number` becomes 'nu,ber' type, that's how `taxNumber` can be consider as number as `let taxNumber: number`, so why it is no type conversion involved?

Comment: Type assertions are you telling the compiler what the type of a value is; it has no runtime effect at all.  If you write `let foo = (Math.random() < 0 ? "a" : 1) as string` you are not turning `foo` into a `string` at runtime; you are *lying* to the compiler about what type `foo` will be at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

> so why it is no type conversion involved?

They're pointing out that when you run the code, whatever the javascript code returns is what it returns. Doing `as number` doesn't change the behavior of the code, it's just a way of telling typescript "i know better than you, so don't check my types here".

If you truly do know better than typescript does, then type assertions are ok. But if you make a mistake (eg, if you say it's a number when it isn't), you'll have a bug in your code that typescript won't be able to tell you about.

By the way, you can do safer types on this function by using overloads:

```
function calculateTax(amount: number, format: true): string;
function calculateTax(amount: number, format: false): number;
function calculateTax(amount: number, format: boolean): string | number {
   const calcAmount = amount * 1.2;
   return format ? `$${calcAmount.toFixed(2)}` : calcAmount;
}

let taxNumber: number = calculateTax(100, false);
let taxString: string = calculateTax(100, true);
```